# PHP регистрация при выключенных куки

Tags: php, cookie, сессия, регистрация, memcached

Уважаемые специалисты помогите с вопросом. На сайте есть форма регистрации, в качестве логина указывается E-mail, после заполнения полей формы на почту отправляется код подтверждения, который необходимо вписать в соответствующее поле (наподобие SMS кода). Код подтверждения генерируется случайно и запоминается в переменную сессии, а затем когда пользователь его вводит и отправляет, то выполняется проверка

```
if ($_SESSION['code'] == $_POST['code']) { код верный }
```

Еще также считается количество неудачных попыток, тоже в сессии

```
if ($_SESSION['code'] != $_POST['code']) { $_SESSION['i']++; }
```

С включенными Куки проблем не возникает, но а как быть в случае с отключенными куки где сессии не работают? Как запомнить сгенерированный код, как считать количество попыток? Думаю сохранять значения в Memcached, но это как-то не по назначению. Есть ли штатные средства на такой случай?

Comment: Я бы просто запретил регистрацию при выключенных куках и не парился

Comment: @andreymal Как определить включены ли у пользователя куки? Раньше насколько я знаю необходимо было выполнять переадресацию с передачей get параметра не очень удобная процедура.

Comment: По отсутствию сессии. Если при открытии формы регистрации сессия была создана, а при отправке формы сессии всё равно нет, то с куками явно что-то не так (можно не так топорно проверять, но суть примерно такая)

Comment: @ИгорьСаламов, пере регистрацией пользователь заходит на страницу где должен ввести данные. Вот в этот момент и должна генерироваться сессия. Добавьте в свой скрипт, чтобы при открытии ставилась регистрации в сессию записывался какой-то параметр. При регистрации проверяйте этот параметр на наличие, и если его нету, то выводите сообщение что для регистрации нужно включить куки

Comment: @YuriyProkopets благодарю, а можно делать так: `if ($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']) { echo("Куки включены"); }` или нельзя?

Comment: Можно, но мой вариант сразу предполагает защиту от CSRF (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)

Comment: @YuriyProkopets Спасибо, а что может сделать злоумышленник в этом случае?

Comment: Например, простым скриптом нарегистрировать вам кучу фейковых аккаунтов

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете установить для session.use_only_cookies значение "0", чтобы PHP принудительно добавлял идентификатор сеанса к URL-адресам

```
<?php
    ini_set("session.use_cookies", 0);
    ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", 0);
    ini_set("session.use_trans_sid", 1);
    ini_set("session.cache_limiter", "");
    session_start();
```

Но это небезопасно в случае если нужно кому-то скопировать URL на что-то

Comment: Благодарю, небезопасно тем, что кто-то может получить чужой sessid и зайти под его именем?

Comment: @ИгорьСаламов ну да. то есть ты кому-то кидаешь например ссылку на статью (условно) типа чувак почитай круто написано, а у тя в конце урла ID сессии прилеплен. ну это опять-же костыль, а для костыля простительно. если юзер выключил у себя куки, значит, ССЗБ